# Golf versus non-golf questions

Tags: discussion, tags

[This question](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25/code-golf-answers-that-arent-golfing-attempts) raised the issue of questions that do not make mention of being golf questions. Sometimes answerers [assume it's a golfing question and golf it, leading others to follow suit](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4/rot-13-transform-standard-input) and then a [non-golfed answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4/rot-13-transform-standard-input/48#48) looks out of place.

We badly need a way to enforce distinction of golf vs non-golf questions. I think the solution is to enforce one of a set of tags (like on meta) that defines the puzzle type is the solution. Any other ideas?

Comment: I agree completely. But for non-golf questions how do you decide the "right" answer? In particular http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/262/print-1-to-1000-in-c-without-semi-colons you state that the " Preference will be given to clever solution." What one might consider "clever" is subjective. I agree its a great question but the answer chosen will be subjective and difficult to award.

Comment: @snmcdonald http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69/picking-an-answer And by the way, I'm posting these different questions styles purposefully to try pick out issues like this now.

Comment: Here's another question potentially at fault: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/504/stable-positive-negative-separation I've asked OP for clarification.

Answer (score 4):

I think we should classify the question on this site in 3 category: `code-golf`, `puzzle` and `obfuscation`. Each category has is own definition. Code-Golf is about solving the problem with the least amount of character. Puzzle is about finding solution to a problem with different approach. Obfuscation is about doing code obfuscation.

We could do like on MSO and force that we provide at least one of the tag to make sure all question are well defined.

Answer (score 4):

`code-golf` vs. `coding-challenge` seem sufficient to me, the distinction here being that golf problems aren't generally trying to solve anything that isn't basically trivial unless you are golfing.  A coding challenge on the other hand is something that's at least mildly difficult to solve.

Comment: How about we drop the `coding-`? All posts will be about code after all. We could also shorten `code-golf` to `golf`, but I'm less sure about that.

Comment: @marcog: In the early SO days, I did indeed use the `golf` tag for code golf, on the understanding that (PGA) golf is totally off-topic for SO. I was completely overruled, though. (I wanted to hunt down the meta.SO through where this happened, but I think it's been nuked.) It'd be interesting to try to reopen this topic for this site.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as how the name of this site is code-golf, I think everyone is going to assume golfing is supposed to happen

Comment: It doesn't have to remain that way. See [this](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5/site-title-and-domain).

Answer (score -2):

A set of tags for criteria makes sense. e.g. a `golf` tag and an `anti-golf` tag and maybe (though this is debatable) an `obsfucation` tag. one of which *must* be applied to any question

Comment: I suppose, that `anti-golf` is too subjective and looks like usual reason for close questions on any stackexchange site because of *questions of this type are too open ended*. Also see current ideas about *must be* tags [here](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6/what-should-be-the-rules-for-questions-on-this-site/8#8) and [here](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/14/is-code-challenge-necessary).

Comment: No one's going to come up with a complete set of tags, unless we want to reject all question types we can't think of at the moment.

Comment: no one said the set _had_ to be static, just that all actual code questions must have a criteria-type tag... you can create new tags at question asking time